# What is the login popup for and how do I disable it?

Tags: settings, networking

I'm talking about this annoying thing whenever I disconnect from the Internet. It fixes itself when I reconnect to the Internet and I can move it out of the way and still proceed with my activities, but its just annoying:

[the giant white box in the middle that can't connect to elementary.io for some reason]

[image]